# Swap elements in array with various data types

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I was looking around SO for an answer, and I did get some insight, but can't quite get to a desired solution. My issue is this:

So I have a keypad with number 1 through 5, and when I select one of the number keys, it moves it to an array called `numberPad`, as an object, like so:

```js
[
  { number: 1, alias: 'one', checked: true, option: 'Option for key 1' },
  { number: 4, alias: 'four', checked: true, option: 'Option for key 4' }
]
```

And then it renders each index of `numberPad` as a styled card, and each `number` is its own clickable dropdown button. When clicking on the rendered number, a separate list of buttons (* also 1 through 5*) becomes visible, and if, on that new list of buttons, a number is clicked that is not in the `numberPad` array, then that data is pushed to `numberPad`. If the number exists in `numberPad`, this where I need to make something happen...

So let's say 1 and 4 are rendered, and I click on the number 4  to open the list of buttons. If I now select 1, since it is already in the data array, I want to swap just the `option` value between the two.

So, I click on 4, the button list opens, and I click on 1, I want my array to look like this:

```
[
  { number: 1, alias: 'one', checked: true, option: 'Option for key 4' },
  { number: 4, alias: 'four', checked: true, option: 'Option for key 1' }
]
```

I am having some trouble getting there. I have seen many answers on SO about a swap function, but those seem to swap the entire index with another index, where as I only want to swap one key/value pair on a click.

Does anyone have any advice here please...? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I feel silly. I already had this swap function that I wrote:

```
swapArray = (input, i, j) => {
  // do not mutate original array
  const copyArray = input.slice(0);

  [copyArray[i], copyArray[j]] = [copyArray[j], copyArray[i]];

  return copyArray;
};
```

All I had to do was extend the function like so:

```
swapArray = (input, i, j, data) => {
  // do not mutate original array
  const copyArray = input.slice(0);

  [copyArray[i][data], copyArray[j][data]] = [copyArray[j][data], copyArray[i][data]];

  return copyArray;
};
```

Then all I had to do for my above `numberPad` array is:

```
swapArray(numberPad, 0, 1, 'option')
```

And it yields the correct result. No idea how I didn't realize that right away. Mods, feel free to close this question please...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the objects will be the input from the array which you mentioned in the question and made the changes accordingly. I'm mutating the same data object based on the requirement. Hope this function help you with what you are looking for.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "number": 1,
    "alias": "one",
    "checked": true,
    "option": "Option for key 1"
  },
  {
    "number": 4,
    "alias": "four",
    "checked": true,
    "option": "Option for key 4"
  }
]

let swapOptions = (clickedObj, selectedObj) => {
    const selectedObjIndex = data.findIndex(d => d.number === selectedObj.number)
    if(selectedObjIndex === -1) {
        data.push(selectedObj);
        return;
    } 
    clickedObjIndex = data.findIndex(d => d.number === clickedObj.number)
    data.splice(clickedObjIndex, 1, {...clickedObj, option: selectedObj.option})
    data.splice(selectedObjIndex, 1, {...selectedObj, option:clickedObj.option})
}


swapOptions(data[1], data[0])
console.log(data)

swapOptions(data[0], {
  "number": 5,
  "alias": "one",
  "checked": true,
  "option": "Option for key 5"
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I dono, that just seems a little bit overkill for what I need. I think just extending the `swap` function that I have above is significantly less code, and yields the same result that I need. All I'll ever need to do is swap certain key/value pairs between the objects inside the `numberPad` array...